# Is Instruments 9.3 crashing apps for anyone else?

Tags: xcode-instruments

When I run my App with xCode all loads and runs fine. When I load in Instruments and press record using a profiling template of Activity Monitor or Allocations it loads and runs fine. However if I use Zombies or Leaks the app crashes instantly. I dont even get to see it. I then access the crash logs in xcode and though the reason for the crash is
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Its almost impossible to debug the cause as each report is different.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)  
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010  
VM Region Info: 0x10 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4297687024  
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL  
      UNUSED SPACE AT START  
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000100298000-0000000100388000 [  960K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...p/MyApp  


Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11  
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb  
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]  
Triggered by Thread:  0  


Filtered syslog:  
None found  


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread  
Thread 0 Crashed:  
0   libswiftFoundation.dylib       0x0000000100cf89fc 0x100c4c000 + 707068  
1   MyApp                   0x0000000100310cbc specialized JSONParser.jsonURL(_:jsonType:) + 494780 (JSONParser.swift:51)  
2   MyApp                   0x0000000100310cbc specialized JSONParser.jsonURL(_:jsonType:) + 494780 (JSONParser.swift:51)  
3   MyApp                   0x00000001002efd2c StoreManager.getProductIdentifiersFromServer() + 359724 (StoreManager.swift:57)  
4   MyApp                   0x0000000100329db0 specialized AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 597424 (StoreManager.swift:46)  
5   MyApp                   0x0000000100326a40 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 584256 (AppDelegate.swift:0)  
6   UIKit                         0x000000018f4a1ca8 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 408  
7   UIKit                         0x000000018f68fe14 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3484  
8   UIKit                         0x000000018f694ce4 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1680  
9   UIKit                         0x000000018f92db20 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 784  
10  UIKit                         0x000000018fc05c78 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160  
11  UIKit                         0x000000018f92d79c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 240  
12  UIKit                         0x000000018f92dfdc -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 724  
13  UIKit                         0x00000001900accf4 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 296  
14  UIKit                         0x00000001900acb7c -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432  
15  UIKit                         0x000000018fe1f44c __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220  
16  UIKit                         0x000000018ffb5c5c _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112  
17  UIKit                         0x000000018fe1f304 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 248  
18  UIKit                         0x000000018fc05318 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 368  
19  UIKit                         0x000000018f6933e4 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540  
20  UIKit                         0x000000018faa7490 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364  
21  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001878d7470 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364  
22  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001878dfd6c __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224  
23  libdispatch.dylib             0x00000001849f0ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16  
24  libdispatch.dylib             0x00000001849f81f4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224  
25  FrontBoardServices             0x000000018790b878 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36  
26  FrontBoardServices             0x000000018790b51c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404  
27  FrontBoardServices             0x000000018790bab8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56  
28  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185099614 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24  
29  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185098e3c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276  
30  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001850969ac __CFRunLoopRun + 1204  
31  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184fb6fe8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552  
32  GraphicsServices               0x0000000186f7e020 GSEventRunModal + 100  
33  UIKit                         0x000000018f497090 UIApplicationMain + 236  
34  MyApp                   0x00000001002ab444 main + 78916 (AppDelegate.swift:16)  
35  libdyld.dylib                 0x0000000184a55fc0 start + 4
```

So I stop calling the line

```
StoreManager.getProductIdentifiersFromServer()
```

which stops the subsequent calls to

```
JSONParser.jsonURL(_:jsonType:)
```

Then the app crashes

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)  
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000  
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4365631488  
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL  
      UNUSED SPACE AT START  
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000104364000-0000000104454000 [  960K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...p/MyApp  


Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11  
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb  
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]  
Triggered by Thread:  0  


Filtered syslog:  
None found  


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread  
Thread 0 Crashed:  
0   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184fdf83c CFStringGetCharacterAtIndex + 24  
1   CoreFoundation                 0x000000018508e6c8 normalizeQuintuplet + 148  
2   CoreFoundation                 0x000000018508ee64 -[_CFXPreferences+ 917092 (SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 108  
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185132ae8 -[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:] + 124  
4   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185135384 _CFPreferencesCopyAppValueWithContainer + 116  
5   Foundation                     0x0000000185a2e7d0 -[NSUserDefaults+ 51152 (NSUserDefaults) objectForKey:] + 52  
6   Foundation                     0x0000000185a37240 -[NSUserDefaults+ 86592 (NSUserDefaults) stringForKey:] + 24  
7   MyApp                   0x00000001043cc0dc specialized SettingsTableViewController.init(coder:) + 426204 (SettingsTableViewController.swift:36)  
8   MyApp                   0x00000001043c6a1c @objc SettingsTableViewController.init(coder:) + 403996 (SettingsTableViewController.swift:27)  
9   UIKit                         0x000000018f9c051c -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 248  
10  UIKit                         0x000000018fb6d99c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 688  
11  UIKit                         0x000000018fb6d6d4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 312  
12  UIKit                         0x000000018f9c01c4 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 188  
13  UIKit                         0x000000018fb6d99c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 688  
14  UIKit                         0x000000018fb6db14 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1064  
15  UIKit                         0x000000018fb6d6d4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 312  
16  UIKit                         0x000000018f9bf514 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1164  
17  UIKit                         0x000000018fd44068 -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 196  
18  MyApp                   0x00000001043fcfb4 specialized ApplicationsTabBarController.createViewControllerForTabBarController(storyBoardName:restorationIdentifier:tabBarItemTitle:tabBarItemTag:tabBarItemImage:tabBarItemSelectedImage:) + 626612 (ApplicationsTabBarController.swift:190)  
19  MyApp                   0x00000001043f93c8 ApplicationsTabBarController.setUpViewControllers() + 611272 (ApplicationsTabBarController.swift:79)  
20  MyApp                   0x00000001043fad04 @objc ApplicationsTabBarController.viewWillAppear(_:) + 617732 (ApplicationsTabBarController.swift:0)  
21  UIKit                         0x000000018f44c6b4 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 616  
22  UIKit                         0x000000018f44c424 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 140  
23  UIKit                         0x000000018f4aba60 -[UIViewController viewWillMoveToWindow:] + 704  
24  UIKit                         0x000000018f43bde4 -[UIView+ 97764 (Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 584  
25  UIKit                         0x000000018f43b0cc -[UIView+ 94412 (Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 424  
26  UIKit                         0x000000018f43a88c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 816  
27  UIKit                         0x000000018f437864 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 272  
28  UIKit                         0x000000018f4a5cd0 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48  
29  MyApp                   0x00000001043f639c specialized AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 598940 (AppDelegate.swift:0)  
30  MyApp                   0x00000001043f2bc4 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 584644 (AppDelegate.swift:0)  
31  UIKit                         0x000000018f4a1ca8 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 408  
32  UIKit                         0x000000018f68fe14 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3484  
33  UIKit                         0x000000018f694ce4 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1680  
34  UIKit                         0x000000018f92db20 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 784  
35  UIKit                         0x000000018fc05c78 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160  
36  UIKit                         0x000000018f92d79c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 240  
37  UIKit                         0x000000018f92dfdc -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 724  
38  UIKit                         0x00000001900accf4 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 296  
39  UIKit                         0x00000001900acb7c -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432  
40  UIKit                         0x000000018fe1f44c __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220  
41  UIKit                         0x000000018ffb5c5c _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112  
42  UIKit                         0x000000018fe1f304 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 248  
43  UIKit                         0x000000018fc05318 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 368  
44  UIKit                         0x000000018f6933e4 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540  
45  UIKit                         0x000000018faa7490 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364  
46  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001878d7470 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364  
47  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001878dfd6c __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224  
48  libdispatch.dylib             0x00000001849f0ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16  
49  libdispatch.dylib             0x00000001849f81f4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224  
50  FrontBoardServices             0x000000018790b878 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36  
51  FrontBoardServices             0x000000018790b51c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404  
52  FrontBoardServices             0x000000018790bab8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56  
53  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185099614 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24  
54  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185098e3c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276  
55  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001850969ac __CFRunLoopRun + 1204  
56  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184fb6fe8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552  
57  GraphicsServices               0x0000000186f7e020 GSEventRunModal + 100  
58  UIKit                         0x000000018f497090 UIApplicationMain + 236  
59  MyApp                   0x0000000104378b3c main + 84796 (AppDelegate.swift:16)  
60  libdyld.dylib                 0x0000000184a55fc0 start + 4
```

Does not seem to matter what functions I do or do not call I get a crash. It seems to me that its a system call and not one that I make thats causing the crash. Is it just me or is Instruments 9.3 crashing on Zombies and Or Leaks for anyone else?

Comment: Have this same issue. Crashes at totally different places every time. Did you find a solution? Im also on 9.3

Comment: No not as yet. Downloaded latest Xcode yesterday so will try it again today and report back

Comment: Latest xCode includes version 9.3 unfortunately

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar problem, and I solved it choosing `Blank` template instead of `Leaks` and then I manually add `Allocations` and `Leaks` with the + button at the top right of the screen.

It was solved on Xcode Version 9.4 (9F1027a)

Comment: You save my day

Answer (score 1):

Apple Developer forums had a helpful response (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/97592):

After setting up the Leaks or Zombies instrument but before beginning recording, go to “File” > “Recording Options...” (⌘⌥R) and uncheck “Record Reference Counts”.  This should allow the instrument to run normally.

Comment: How will disabling recording reference counts influence the profile? Does this disable leak detection?

Comment: It has been a while since I tried this, so I don't remember the details.  Have you tried using instruments in Xcode 10 beta?  (I am not sure if it is fixed, but it is worth a try).

Comment: What you suggested did fix my instant crash issue when running the allocations module in instruments, on XCode 9.4. Thanks for that, btw. But a user on the thread you posted said that by disabling 'Record Reference Counts' caused more leaks to be detected. What I wanted to know was, what else gets messed up when I disable this feature? Besides leak detection apparently :P Are zombies also affected?